# Error while trying to compile simple C++ code in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I get the following error while trying to compile an exercise code from a book.

```
// This program prints a message with your name in it. 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hi! It\'s me.\n";
   cout << "I\'m learning to program!\n";
   return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestCompiler, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And when I disable incremental linking and embed manifest, I get the following and can't start without debugging.

```
'TestCompiler.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestCompiler\Debug\TestCompiler.exe', Symbols loaded.
'TestCompiler.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'TestCompiler.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'TestCompiler.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'TestCompiler.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'TestCompiler.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'TestCompiler.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
The program '[3824] TestCompiler.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Those messages are not errors.

Comment: You are right I copied the wrong messages. The ones I posted show after I disabling "Incremental Linking" and turning off "Embed Manifest". I stil, however, can't start without debugging.